# How to set a shared parameters for a whole course (for each user)?

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I need to set a shared numeric parameter for a user that can be accessed (read/write) from any lesson (each lesson corresponds to a primary objective).

Could you help please? I'm confusing to figure it out from the [standart](http://www.adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/scorm.2004.3ed.confreq.v1.0.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You might find these posts helpful:

http://support.scorm.com/entries/96011-What-is-the-difference-between-a-local-objective-and-a-shared-global-objective-

http://support.scorm.com/forums/35631/entries/67062